# ID/hash simple polygons

Tags: python, polygon

I am looking for a way to assign an ID to simple spatial polygons (no hole, mostly convex). The polygons represent real-life objects, that I don't have precise and exact boundaries for. Some of them are very tightly packed.

As of now, I do have a pair of latitude/longitude of a random point inside the polygon. But now I have a batch of "v2" data for roughly the same polygons. The underlying object might have stayed identical, or slightly moved/changed, or completely disappeared.

Even assuming all of the objects are staying the same, as the measure of their boundaries is not clear, I haven't found a way to assign some form of ID to that object (a hash for instance).

My best shot so far is to give polygons a "meaningless" increasing unique integer as ID. Then identify the coordinates of a kind of center (barycenter, orthocenter,...) for each polygon, then look for the polygon  with the closest center. If one is found to be very similar, they are the same, if it's a bit off, manual verification would be necessary to assess the situation (maybe the underlying object now should be represented by two polygons, or it has significantly moved/changed). If nothing remotely close is found, the object is new.

But this solution doesn't "feel" clean. Defining "close enough" might be tricky, and error-prone, especially for small and close by objects. Is there a better way?

Note: my current tech stack is mostly Python, and data is stored in InfluxDB; I'm open to consider a new database system, but not so much to use ArcGIS/QGIS.